# How can I recycle LDPE or HDPE from plastic mesh tree guards?

Tags: plastic, recycling

I have thousands of plastic mesh tree guards like this one:

[image: plastic mesh tree guard]

The trees are now grown and I would like to recycle them. From a quick search online, they seem made from [UV-resistant high density polythene](https://www.plasticmesh.net/plastic-mesh/tree-guards.html) or from [photodegrabable HDPE or LDPE](https://www.plastic-mesh.net/catalog/extruded-mesh/tree-guard.html). The material seems relatively brittle and rips easily when I pull it from around the tree.

I don't know if I should put them in the general trash bin, the plastic recycling bin, or contact a specialty plastics company for recycling.

How can I ascertain Is this material generally recyclable in the plastics bin, or is it recyclable in general?

Comment: Since you have a lot, contact a specialist company.